# GitHub / GitLab access upon request

Tags: github, gitlab

In GitHub or GitLab, to invite a collaborator, the administrator usually asks the collaborator's email.

Instead, how can the administrator allow anyone to request access through clicking a button on the GitHub / GitLab website?

I remember this was possible on at least one of these websites.

Comment: I think you better to post this in other flatform, like DevOps community

Answer (score 1):

In GitLab, you can [click on request access](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/#request-access-to-a-project):

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/img/request_access_button.png]

> An email is sent to the most recently active project maintainers. Up to ten project maintainers are notified. Any project maintainer can approve or decline the request.
>
> If a project does not have any maintainers, the notification is sent to the most recently active owners of the project’s group.
>
> If you change your mind before your request is approved, select Withdraw Access Request

The [OP Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414763/dean) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444109/github-gitlab-access-upon-request#comment123685624_69445629):

> The maintainer can enable this by making the repo public but with visibility restricted to only project members.

---

With [GitLab 15.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/01/22/gitlab-15-8-released/#create-to-dos-for-group-owners-on-access-request) (January 2023), that will trigger:

> ### Create To-Dos for group owners on access request
>
> Previously, access requests to a group appeared only in the **Access** requests tab in the **Group members** section.
>
> Now, access requests also appear in the group owner’s To-Do List.
>
> As a group owner, having access requests added directly to your To-Do List can help you manage your tasks more efficiently and add members quicker.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/todos.html#get-a-list-of-to-do-items) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/374608).

And, still with See [GitLab 15.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/01/22/gitlab-15-8-released/#create-to-dos-for-project-owners-on-access-requests) (January 2023):

> ### Create To-Dos for project owners on access requests
>
> Previously, access requests to a project appeared only in the **Access** requests tab in the **Project members** section.
>
> Now, access requests also appear in the project owner’s To-Do List.
>
> As a project owner, having access requests added directly to your To-Do List can help you manage your tasks more efficiently and add members quicker.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/todos#actions-that-create-to-do-items) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/374725).

Comment: The maintainer can enable this by making the repo public but with visibility restricted to only project members (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Dean OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.